# Css Move element from left to right animated

Tags: html, css

I have an element that needs to be move from left to right and right to left when I change the left, right variables.

Here is an jsfiddle example that I'm working on it. It moves left to right and right to left but there is no animation.

What I am doing wrong?

**CSS:**

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/1/)

```
div
{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background:red;
   transition-property: right, left;
   transition-duration: 2s;
   -webkit-transition-property: right, left; /* Safari */
   -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
   position:absolute;
}
div:hover
{
   right:0px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/2/ Like this?

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/3/)!

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/7/) view this demo       right:calc(100% - 100px);

Comment: [right to left](http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/9/) hi check it

Comment: By "left and right variables" do you mean "left and right properties"? Where did you get the idea that Safari requires vendor prefixes?

Answer (score 17):

It's because you aren't giving the un-hovered state a `right` attribute.

`right` isn't set so it's trying to go from nothing to `0px`. Obviously because it has nothing to go to, it just 'warps' over.

If you give the unhovered state a `right:90%;`, it will transition how you like.

Just as a side note, if you still want it to be on the very left of the page, you can use the `calc` css function.

Example:

```
right: calc(100% - 100px)
                     ^ width of div
```

You don't have to use `left` then.

Also, you can't transition using `left` or `right` `auto` and will give the same 'warp' effect.

```css
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    transition:2s;
    -webkit-transition:2s;
    -moz-transition:2s;
    position:absolute;
    right:calc(100% - 100px);
}
div:hover {
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.
</p>
<div></div>
<p>Hover over the red square to see the transition effect.</p>
```

[CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) says that the `calc()` function only works on `IE10`+

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```css
div
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  position:absolute;
}
div:hover
{
  transform: translate(3em,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(3em,0);
  -moz-transform: translate(3em,0);
  -o-transform: translate(3em,0);
  -ms-transform: translate(3em,0);
}
```

```html
<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
<div></div>
<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LKcsA)

Comment: Why are you using obsolete vendor prefixes?

Comment: What is the advantage of using `transform` over `left` and `right`?

Answer (score 3):

You should try doing it with **css3 animation**. Check the code bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst 5s infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    25%  {background: yellow; left: 200px; top: 0px;}
    50%  {background: blue; left: 200px; top: 200px;}
    75%  {background: green; left: 0px; top: 200px;}
    100% {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}

@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    25%  {background: yellow; left: 200px; top: 0px;}
    50%  {background: blue; left: 200px; top: 200px;}
    75%  {background: green; left: 0px; top: 200px;}
    100% {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The animation-direction property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Where 'div' is your animated object.

I hope you find this useful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the advantage of animation over transitions in this case, other than being more verbose?

Comment: The OP wasn't using animations, he was using transitions.

Comment: Can you pt the 2 blocks together if they are the same? Like `@-webkit-keyframes myfirst,  @keyframes myfirst { ... }`